# Domain Redirects SEO relative to the root folder

Tags: seo

I got two related problems in the site root.

First, both "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" works the same way. Is that a problem for SEO purposes? Some guy told to use a redirect. Should I do that? What redirect should I use?

Second, my visitors that visit the site over the "/" url get geolocated and redirect to a specfic page, it means, if the visitor access "www.domain.com" from the city a, he gets a redirect to "www.domain.com/a/", if the visitor came from city b, he gets a redirect to "www.domain.com/b/", etc... How should I work over that?

PS: Feel free to rename the question, I dont know how to name it properly.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First point answer**:

Yes, you should redirect it. Otherwise you can run into the **[duplicated content issue](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66359)**. You can redirect using .htaccess and the code will be this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^site\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,nc,L]
```

**Second point answer**:

You can use .htaccess also in this case. But for this question, please bear [this discussion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/should-i-make-a-search-engine-only-page-for-my-domain-which-re-directs-visitors/20730) in mind (especially my answer).